# Change PDF's hyperlink display text

Tags: itext

Using iTextSharp how can I modify the display text of hyperlink in a pdf document. I can change the annotation link, but my target is to change the displaying text of the hyperlink not the actual web link. Is it possible?
I don't want to add a new anchor, I just want to modify the existing anchor with a different text, not changing existing web link.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

use this,

```
using (FileStream msReport = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~") + "/App_Data/" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".pdf", FileMode.Create))
{
     Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 20, 10);
     PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, msReport);
     doc.Open();
     Font link = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.UNDERLINE, BaseColor.BLUE);
     Anchor anchor = new Anchor("google", link);
     anchor.Reference = "https://www.google.co.in";
     doc.Add(anchor);
     doc.Close();
}
```

Comment: I don't want to add new anchor text string, but to modify the existing anchor text string.

Comment: The text of the "Anchor" isn't an annotation. It's part of a content stream (could be the content stream of a page, or an XObject). Changing that text is often very difficult. Read the intro of http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf and you'll find out that PDF is not a format for edition.